# how to prevent alias expansion by `eval` to an arbitrary alias, and keep the endless loop protection on a function?

Tags: bash, alias, function

IMPORTANT: [do not use eval!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) (I learned this later..)

In a function, `eval` expands `sleep` to its alias, so I prevent the endless loop this way:

```
function FUNCexecEcho() { 
  echo "EXEC: $@";
  shopt -u expand_aliases
  eval "$@";
  shopt -s expand_aliases
};
alias sleep='FUNCexecEcho sleep ';
sleep 10
```

But then, all other aliases will stop working...
How to prevent expansion only to one arbitrary alias inside this function?

PS.: the endless loop only happens on the second time you execute `sleep 10`

Comment: [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)!

Comment: thx, [here another explanation why not use eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `eval` is wrong in the first place. The shell has already evaluated what you pass to `FUNCexecEcho`, evaluating a second time is wrong and potentially dangerous. In your code, you're also discarding the exit status of the command.

```
FUNCexecEcho() { 
  echo "EXEC: $@"
  "$@"
}
```

(no problem with aliases there unless you define an alias for `"$@"`). Compare the behaviour in:

```
FUNCexecEcho echo 'this;rm -rf "$HOME"'
```

with the two versions. With mine, it gives:

```
$ FUNCexecEcho echo 'this;rm -rf "$HOME"'
EXEC: echo this;rm -rf "$HOME"
this;rm -rf "$HOME"
```

I suggest you don't run it with yours if you don't have backups ;-)

Comment: thx, I found this that helped to understand [why we should not use `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

Answer (score 3):

Use a backslash before the command you do not need an alias for.

For example: I use `\ls` when I do not want to invoke aliased version of `ls` which is `ls -thor`.

In the case of eval, you will need a double backslash, eg. `eval \\ls`.

Comment: `eval "\\$@"` worked, and I could remove those `shopt`, thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower - [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the command, `command`. Like so:

```
$ alias echo="command echo 'hi: '"
$ echo "blah"
hi:  blah
```

But I can bypass the alias `echo` like so:

```
$ command echo "blah"
blah
```

Notice I actually used `command` in my `alias` definition as well. This avoids the alias from looping back on itself.